# CSS Width Beyond Specified

Tags: html, css, width

On [this website](http://www.2touchrulz.com/) my CSS is

```
.event_a {
    width:220px;
    float:left;
    height:100%;
    padding:5px 0px 0px 0px;
}
```

But the three '.event_a' boxes will not sit next to each other. When I inspect element in Chrome it's showing me that the width is 740px! (Which would explain why they are not sitting next to each other.)

Any idea why it's not accepting the specified width or how to fix it?

Comment: if you found an answer that works click the green question mark bellow the votes.

Comment: @austinbv Thanks! I've just realized that... Will do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an error in your style sheet. Remove the extra "}":

```
.event1 {
    float:left;
    width:365px;
    height:100%;
    padding:5px 2px 0px 2px;
    }
    }
.event_a {
```

Comment: good to hear it. I run into this one myself a lot. A quick way to debug would be using Firefox and firebug. First with firebug inspect the div in question if you don't see the style you need applied being applied then open up your style sheet to that spot and take a look. You can do this in browser to see what was loaded by opening up the css tab in firebug then right click the name of the css file and select open in new tab (this is a good way to make certain that you remembered to save your work if you are running in multiple dev environments too).